# Cache until expiryDate

Tags: cache

Caching is hard.

I want to delete the cache when a news entry hits it's expiryDate. So I wrote

```
{% set newsExpiration = craft.entries.section('news').first()%}

{% cache until newsExpiration.expiryDate  %}
   Bla
{% endcache %}
```

Now the news entry has expired and no news is present so there is an error:

> Impossible to access an attribute ("expiryDate") on a null variable

I then wanted to write a conditional to see if `newsExpiration` is defined.

```
{% if newsExpiration is defined %}
   {% cache until newsExpiration.expiryDate  %}
{% else %}
   {% cache %}
{% endif %}
```

But that also throws an error because Twig is expecting a closing tag to the cache.

> Unexpected "else" tag (expecting closing tag for the "cache" tag
>   defined near line xy).

I there a proper way to define the cache tag including both present and absent entries without query conditionals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Caching is hard.

https://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/506010907021828096

Something like this should work.

```
{% if newsExpiration is defined %}
    {% cache until newsExpiration.expiryDate  %}
        ...
    {% endcache %}
{% else %}
    {% cache %}
        ...
    {% endcache %}
{% endif %}
```

You'd probably want to use an [include](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/include.html) for the body of the two cache tags to keep things [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).